# Difference between RegExp constructor and Regex literal test function?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm confused on how this is possible...

```
var matcher = new RegExp("d", "gi");
matcher.test(item)
```

The code above contains the following values

```
item = "Douglas Enas"
matcher = /d/gi
```

Yet when I run the matcher.test function back to back I get true for the first run and false for the second run.

```
matcher.test(item) // true
matcher.test(item) // false
```

If I use a regexp literal such as

```
/d/gi.test("Douglas Enas")
```

and run it back to back in chrome I get true both times. Is there an explanation for this?

Sample of a back to back run in chrome console creating a regexp object using constructor

```
matcher = new RegExp("d","gi")
/d/gi

matcher.test("Douglas Enas")
true

matcher.test("Douglas Enas")
false

matcher
/d/gi
```

Sample using back to back calls on literal

```
/d/gi.test("Douglas Enas")
true

/d/gi.test("Douglas Enas")
true
```

The reason for this question if because using the RegExp constructor and the test function against a list of values I'm losing matches... However using the literal I'm getting back all the values I expect

**UPDATE**

```
                        var suggestions = [];

                        ////process response  
                        $.each(responseData, function (i, val)
                        {
                            suggestions.push(val.desc);
                        });


                        var arr = $.grep(suggestions, function(item) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp("d", "gi");
                            return matcher.test(item);
                        });
```

Moving the creation of the matcher inside the closure included the missing results.  the "d" is actually a dynamically created string but I used "d" for simplicity sake.  I'm still not sure now creating a new expression every time I do the test when I am iterating over the suggestions array would inadvertently exclude results is a little confusing still, and probably has something to do with the advancement of the match test

Comment: I cant reproduce the issue, I get true everytime for this code : var matcher = new RegExp("d", "gi"); matcher.test("Douglas Enas");

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

> `test` called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.

So basically when you have an instance of `RegExp`, each call to `test` advances the matcher. Once you've found the first `d`, it will look beyond that and try to find *another* `d`. Well, there are none anymore, so it returns `false`.

On the other hand, when you do:

```
/d/gi.test("Douglas Enas")
```

You create a new `RegExp` instance every time on the spot, so it will always find that first `d` (and thus return `true`).

Comment: So in the case of using it with a grep in jquery
`var matcher = new RegExp("d", "gi");
                            var arr = $.grep(suggestions, function(item) {
                                return matcher.test(item);
                            });`

How would that exclude matching values?

Comment: ah I moved the creation of the regex inside the closure and it included the missing values...
var arr = $.grep(suggestions, function(item) {
                                var matcher = new RegExp("d", "gi");
                                return matcher.test(item);
                            });

Answer (score 0):

According to Mozilla Developer Network,

> As with exec (or in combination with it), test called multiple times
>   on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the
>   previous match.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the link ATM, but as I recall, this is a known issue with the `test` method in combination with a `g` pattern: the match position isn't *"forgotten"* somehow. Either drop the global flag *and/or* use the `.match` method, and it'll work just fine.